# Correct usage of the prepositions 'for' and 'in'

Tags: prepositions

Which of these is correct? Why is it correct?

1. It is natural **for** every man to wish for distinction.
2. It is natural **in** every man to wish for distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the first sentence seems to be more appropriate as per the following structure of the sentence :

> It + linking verb + adjective + FOR something/somebody + TO-infinitive :

It is natural for every man to wish for distinction.

NOTE:
In other cases, different prepositions are possible after 'natural' :
He is natural in speaking English fluently.
It is natural in look.
It seemed completely natural to me.
It is natural with human beings.
There is nothing natural about it.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions can be rearranged:
1. To wish for distinction is natural **for** every man.
2. To wish for distinction is natural **in** every man.
to show that the question is just that of which preposition to use.

Either preposition works.

The sense of "for" is here:
[Merriam-Webster "for" (4)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)
"...indicates suitability or fitness"

The sense of "in" is here:
[Merriam-Webster "in" 1a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in-)
"... indicate inclusion, location..."

So, both "for" and "in" work. This can be verified by searching Google Books for "natural for every man" and "natural in every man". Both will be found, though the expression with "for" is more common.